# Errors upon booting up with ubuntu

Tags: error-handling

Everytime I boot up ubuntu, I keep on receiving errors. They differ every time I boot up. My original one which I solved by **recovery** was

```
`/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, check forced. Inodes that were part of a corrupt orphan linked list found.

/dev/sda2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. Fsck exited with status code 4.
```

After the recovery I managed to finally get through to my desktop. I then used the **"boot repair"** tool.

However, it is still managing to boot to the desktop but I am receiving this two new errors.

My two **new** errors:

```
"error: failure reading sector 0x47f864c0 from 'hd0'."

"ata1.00: failed command: WRITE FPDMA QUEUED"
"can't request region for resource [mem 0x34fff000-0xo4fff02f]
```

My feeling is this has something to do with the hard disk.

Comment: Your disk is failing.

Comment: Would I be able to fix my hard disk? Or will I have to get a new one? It can't be completely failing if I am managing to still boot it through the desktop, though.

Comment: Most likely you will need to buy a new disk. Run fsck from a LiveUSB first.

Comment: When I run in terminal it says:

Comment: 0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action

Comment: which action should I take?